# How to show image from both url and uiimage in the same time in collection view in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I need to show images from both url and uiimage in a collectionview.

The scenerio is images are coming from the api and user can add other image in the collection view.

Here is the code that I am using right now ?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return savedPhotosArray.count + 1

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = checkOutCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)as! CheckOutCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
        img.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.addSubview(img)
        img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus")
        img.backgroundColor = blackThemeColor
    }else{
        let img2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.size.width, height: cell.frame.size.height))
        img2.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        img2.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.addSubview(img2)

        if let image = savedPhotosArray[indexPath.row - 1] as? String
        {
            let imageStr = basePhotoUrl + image
            print (imageStr)

            let imageUrl = URL(string: imageStr)
            img2.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl , placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "car-placeholder"))
        }
```

}

Here index = 0 is used to add images from imagePicker.

Comment: Unrelated but why the `if - else` expression in `numberOfItemsInSection`? If `count` is 0 then `savedPhotosArray.count + 1` is 1.

Comment: As need to show plus image at the first cell to add images

Comment: Yes, but `savedPhotosArray.count + 1` returns always the correct value. What is 0 + 1?

Comment: yes you are right... Can you provide solution for my problem ?

Comment: what the issue ....

Comment: Need to show images from both url and UIImage (that will be added from UIImagePicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a struct like this

```
struct Item {

    var isLocal:Bool
    var imageNameUrl:String

}
```

//

```
var savedPhotosArray  = [Item(isLocal:true, imageNameUrl:"local.png"),Item(isLocal:false, imageNameUrl:"remoteExtension")]
```

//

Also don't add the images inside `cellForRowAt` as cells are reusable and this glitches the UI  plus memory leaks , make the imageView inside the cell xib or if programmatically and assign only in `cellForRowAt`